# How find this $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

How find this 
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^6}\right)$$

I think we can find this value have closed form
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^{2k}}\right)$$
since
$$1-\dfrac{1}{n^6}=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
so I think we must find this
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
and
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  You might consider finding a common denominator and factoring.  Or you could try taking log of the product.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673495/prod-i-1-infty1-fracki3-for-integer-k/673499#673499).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mhenni Benghorbal mentioned, there is a similar problem which has been treated yesterday and I shall use a similar approach to the one he proposed.

$$\prod_{n=2}^{m}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)=\frac{\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{3 \pi  m^3 \Gamma (m)^2}$$
and
$$\prod_{n=2}^{m}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)=\frac{(m+1) \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \pi  \Gamma (m+1)^2}$$ So, the product, from $n=2$ to $n=m$, write $$\frac{(m+1) \cosh ^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(m+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{6 \pi ^2 m^5 \Gamma (m)^4}$$ If $m$ goes to infinity, the limit is then $$\frac{1+\cosh \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)}{12 \pi ^2} =\dfrac{\cosh^2\left(\pi\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\right)}{6\pi^2}$$ as shown by Lucian.

Comment: The connection between the Gammas of the odd exponents and the sines of the even ones is the result of [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: @Lucian. Thank you for that since I learn a lot from you. I must say that I really like your answer. I thought that extending what was done on yesterday was also an interesting execrcise. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

$$P_6(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{x^6}{\pi^6n^6}\bigg)=\frac{\sin x}{x^3}\cdot\frac{\cosh\big(x\sqrt3\big)-\cos x}2\quad$$

See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). For $x\to\pi$, use [l'Hopital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule) after first dividing through $1-\dfrac{x^6}{\pi^6}$ , in order to finally arrive at $\dfrac{\cosh^2\left(\pi\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\right)}{6\pi^2}$ . In general, $P_{2k}(x)=s_k\displaystyle\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\sin\Big((-1)^{j/k}x\Big)}x$ , where $s_k$ forms a cycle of length four, $(+,+,-,-)$, starting with $k=1$. And, of course, when $x\to\pi$, use [l'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule) after first dividing through $1-\bigg(\dfrac x\pi\bigg)^{2k}$, just as before. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is a method of directly evaluating the product which I have been applying to a number of products.

Set

\begin{align*}
f(x) = x^3 \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^6}{n^6} \right)
\end{align*}

Taking logs and differentiating with respect to $x$ gives:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) = \frac{3}{x} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\left( - \frac{6x^5}{n^6} \right)}{\left( 1 - \frac{x^6}{n^6} \right)} = \frac{3}{x} -6 x^5 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6 - x^6}
\end{align*}

The sum can be evaluated by employing the fact that the function

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\tan \pi z}
\end{align*}

has simple poles at all integers $n$. This allows us to write

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6 - x^6} = \frac{1}{2 i} \oint_C \dfrac{1}{(z^6 - x^6) \tan \pi z} dz
\end{align*}

where the contour $C$ is defined in fig (a). The dots are poles at non-zero integer values of $z$, whereas the crosses mark the location of the other poles of $\dfrac{1}{(z^6 - x^6) \tan \pi z}$.

[image]

We have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6 - x^6} & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6 - x^6} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{n^6 - x^6} = \frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{C+C'} \dfrac{1}{(z^6 - x^6) \tan \pi z} dz
\end{align*}

where the contour $C'$ is defined in fig (a). We complete the path of integration along semicircles at infinity (see fig (b)) since the integration along them vanishes. Since the resulting enclosed area contains a finite number of singularities marked by crosses, we can shrink this contour down to a contour, $C_s$, surrounding these finite number of poles (see fig (c)). So that

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) =  \frac{3}{x} -6 x^5 \frac{1}{4i} \oint_{C_s} \frac{dz}{(z^6-x^6) \tan \pi z}  \qquad (*)
\end{align*}

The are poles at $z = 0, x, xe^{i2\pi/6}, xe^{i2\pi 2/6}, xe^{i2\pi 3/6} , xe^{i2\pi 4/6} , xe^{i2\pi 5/6}$. These are marked by crosses in the figures. Note

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z \rightarrow x e^{ \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6} } } \frac{z^{6} - x^{6}}{z - x \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} = \lim_{z \rightarrow x e^{ \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6} } } \frac{\dfrac{d}{dz} (z^{6} - x^{6})}{\dfrac{d}{dz} (z - x \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6})} = \lim_{z \rightarrow x e^{ \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6} } } 6 z^5 = 6 x^5 e^{- \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}}
\end{equation}

Using this we evaluate $(*)$ to obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) & = \frac{3}{x} - 6 x^5 \frac{1}{4i} (-2 \pi i) \left[ \frac{1}{-x^6 \pi} + \sum_{q=0}^5 \dfrac{ e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} }{6 x^5 \tan \pi (e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} x)} 
\right]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{q=0}^5 \dfrac{ e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} }{\tan \pi (e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} x)}
\end{eqnarray}

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ \sum_{q=0}^{5} \frac{d}{dx} \ln \sin  [e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} \pi x ]
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = C \left[ \prod_{q=0}^5 \sin [e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} \pi x ]
\right]^{1/2}
\end{eqnarray}

So

\begin{eqnarray}
C \left[ \prod_{q=0}^5 \sin [e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} \pi x ]
\right]^{1/2} = x^3 \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^6}{n^6} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Using $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin [A x]/x = A$, we have

\begin{equation}
1 = C \pi^3 \sqrt{ \prod_{q=0}^5 e^{ \frac{i 2 \pi q}{6} } } = C \pi^3 \sqrt{ e^{\frac{i 2 \pi [1+2+ \cdots + 5]}{6}} } = C \pi^3 \sqrt{ e^{ i \pi 5} } = C \pi^3 \sqrt{(-1)^{5}} = C \pi^3 i  . 
\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray}
& x^3 \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^6}{n^6} \right) = -i \frac{1}{\pi^3} \left[ \prod_{q=0}^5 \sin [e^{\frac{i 2 \pi q}{6}} \pi x ]
\right]^{1/2}
\nonumber \\
& = -i \frac{1}{\pi^3} \left[ (-\sin^2 (\pi x)) (- \sin^2 ([\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}] \pi x )) (- \sin^2 ([\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}] \pi x ))
\right]^{1/2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\pi^3} \sin (\pi x) \sin ([\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}] \pi x) ] \sin [\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}] \pi x) ])
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi^3} \sin (\pi x) (\cosh (\sqrt{3} \pi x) - \cos (\pi x))
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray}
x^3 \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^6}{n^6} \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi^3} \sin (\pi x) (\cosh (\sqrt{3} \pi x) - \cos (\pi x))
\end{eqnarray}

Finally, dividing by $1 - x^6$ and taking the limit $x \rightarrow 1$ using l'Hopital

\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{n=2}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^6} \right) = \frac{1 + \cosh (\sqrt{3} \pi)}{12 \pi^2}
\end{eqnarray}