# What's the limit of this product? $\prod_{n=2}^\infty \left(1-\frac1{n^p}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

Sorry I'm really out of any sort of number theory... is this a known product?
\begin{align}
P & = \prod_{n=2}^\infty \left(1-\dfrac1{n^p}\right)
\end{align}
As a special case I would be interested in $p=3$. Thank you very much

Comment: It can be written in terms of the gamma function.

Comment: that would work, can you tell me how?

Comment: The basic idea is to factor $(1-n^{-p})$ into linear terms and utilize the [Weierstrass product for $\Gamma(z)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions) to simply the resulting expression. For a technical reason it is easier to work with partial products first.

Comment: Of course the valuable fact is an understandable proof, which I hope  see from an user to learn it. But here you have a tool for the future (type product (1-1/k^3), k=2 to infinity) in INFINITE PRODUCTS here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+(1-1%2Fk%5E3),+k%3D2+to+infinity

Comment: Just give the infinite product to maple and you will get a closed form!

Comment: [Three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679373) [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674615) [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673495).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Weierstrass product for $\Gamma(z)$, we can easily find that

$$ \frac{e^{(\gamma-1)z}}{\Gamma(2-z)} = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{z}{n} \right) e^{z/n}. $$

Writing

$$ \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^p}\right) = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \prod_{\omega : \omega^p = 1} \left( 1 - \frac{\omega}{n} \right) e^{\omega/n} $$

and interchanging the order of summation, we have

$$ \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^p}\right) = \prod_{\omega : \omega^p = 1} \frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\omega)}. $$

For some special choice of $p$ (such as $p = 2$ or $p = 3$), this can be simplified further.

Comment: Great Answer!!!